# red5 server side script configureation

Tags: maven, red5

I'm having a diffucult time getting a red5 server side script up and running using the eclipse maven plugin on a windows 8 box. I've tried downloading maven binary to create if from the command line. I've tried using maven directly from the command line. I've tried coping files from the red5 templates directory. I've actually bee able to get a serverside script to show no errors in eclipse but when I copy the WEB-INF file over to the red5 server it doesn't work and I know the red5 server is up and able to connect because I can connect to other test applications successfully. How do I create a server side script with eclipse, maven, and red5?
Thanks for your time.

--calmchess

Comment: I found some instructions followed the completely have zero errors or warnings from eclipse. but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: calm and follow a tutorial step by step... you will make that work